# VFOR Loop can't access the global server link

Tags: vuejs2

I have a vue.js 2.0 app ,

Registered my server url as a global variable, like this in **main.js** :

```
Vue.server = Vue.prototype.server = "http://localhost:3000/";
```

Now,I'm trying to display some pics inside of a **v-for loop**, inside of a vue component file **users.vue** :

```
 <div v-for="user in users" class="col-sm col-xs-12">
            <div class="card " style="margin-bottom : 20px">
                <img v-bind:src="this.server + user.img   "   class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{user.nom}}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Voici la description de mon profil .</p>
                    <a v-on:click="route(user._id)" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Profil</a>
                    <!-- <span class="badge badge-warning"> {{ info }}</span>  -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have this **error** :

```
TypeError: "this is undefined"
```

V-for doesn't accept my this.server variable .

How can I access **my global URL** inside of a  **v-for loop**  ?
(P.S : I can access this.server on any classic template, except the v-for)

**EDIT :** Resolved my problem like this  :

```
div v-for="user in users" class="col-sm col-xs-12">
            <div class="card " style="margin-bottom : 20px">
                <img v-bind:src="gettinSrv() + user.img   "   class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{user.nom}}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Voici la description de mon profil .</p>
                    <a v-on:click="route(user._id)" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Profil</a>
                    <!-- <span class="badge badge-warning"> {{ info }}</span>  -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

With this method :

```
 methods: {
        gettinSrv: function () {
          return this.server;
        }
```

**EDIT 2 :** **KCP has the right answer** , please forget edit 1 , thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a simple syntax mistake.
Just use `server` instead of `this.server` inside `v-for` loop.